# Boiling A frog in a sous vidè bath

Tags: homework

So if i were to use a sous vidè water bath and a frog and slowley raised the temperature say 1 to 2 degrees a day would they survive harsh boiling water through thermoregulation

Comment: How will it survive energy depletion?

Comment: could you perhaps provide a bit more context for asking this question?...

Answer (score 2):

No.

No higher order organism has enough proteins that are stable at 100 degrees C to survive. Proteins denature at higher temps and all cellular functions that depend on them cease.

Some [thermophillic bacteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermophile) have evolved proteins that are stable above 100 degrees C over eons of evolution.